# How can i reduce the lines of this long code with python?

Tags: python, maya

i couldn't figure out simplifing this long code below.
plz help me!!

```
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[0], wheelBankGrp[0]+'.rotateX' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[1], wheelBankGrp[0]+'.rotateY' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[2], wheelBankGrp[0]+'.rotateZ' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[3], wheelBankGrp[1]+'.rotateX' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[4], wheelBankGrp[1]+'.rotateY' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[5], wheelBankGrp[1]+'.rotateZ' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[6], wheelBankGrp[2]+'.rotateX' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[7], wheelBankGrp[2]+'.rotateY' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[8], wheelBankGrp[2]+'.rotateZ' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[9], wheelBankGrp[3]+'.rotateX' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[10], wheelBankGrp[3]+'.rotateY' )
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[11], wheelBankGrp[3]+'.rotateZ' )
```

Comment: Loops. See: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: `for i in range(12): mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[i], wheelBankGrp[i//3]+ f'.rotate{"XYZ"[i%3]}' )`

Answer (score 1):

```
rotates = ['.rotateX', '.rotateY', '.rotateZ']
for i in range(12):
    mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C+'.'+bankAttName[i], wheelBankGrp[i//3]+rotates[i%3] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested loops something like this should work

```
   rotations = ['rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ']
    
    for i in range(len(wheelBankGrp)):
        for j in range(len(rotations)):
            mc.connectAttr(bankCon.C + '.' + bankAttName[3*i+j], wheelBankGrp[i] + '.' + rotations[j])
```